# What's the subpatellar tendon?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, anatomy, tendons

I read in Thomas Myers book Anatomy Trains:

> Although the muscles themselves have attachments within the anterior
>   compartment to the tibia, fibula, and interosseous membrane, the next
>   station for the SFL *[Superficial Front Line]* is at the top of both the medial and lateral side
>   of this track, the tibial tuberosity
>
> Continuing in a straight line upward is no problem: the quadriceps
>   begin their upward sweep here with the
>   **subpatellar tendon**. The SFL  includes the patella, the large sesamoid bone designed to hold the SFL away from the knee joint
>   fulcrum so that the tissues of the quadriceps have more leverage for
>   extending the knee.

I can't find the term subpatellar tendon in my anatomy book. What does it refer to? Is it the patella ligament?

Comment: Can you add the text before "Continuing in a straight line upward is no problem" and the definition for SFL?

Comment: @kmm : I did so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are correct, "subpatellar tendon" is referring to the patellar ligament. Although it is small, in the image below, (3) is the tibial tuberosity and (5) is the patella. (4) which is labeled "subpatellar tendon" is between the two. The only structure between them is the patellar ligament. So, I think this is what it meant (though in 20 years of teaching, I haven't heard that terminology).

[image]